# how to convert JSON.stringify($scope.obj) to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

Im passing Scope variables by JSON.stringify to MVC

```
"PP": JSON.stringify($scope.PP)
```

Further I capture it in MVC under `modal.PP`
which now has string type value in this format

```
"{\"bVal\":true,\"sVal\":\"kkkk\"}"
```

Is there any easy method to convert this to array or and simple processable format where I can capture "objName" and its "value"?
**Note: I cant use third party softwares like Nuget**

Comment: Try object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(data);

Comment: What is type of PP?

Comment: now it's a `IDictionary<string,object>`, why not work  with that?

Comment: PP is a angular JS object which has PP.bVal, PP.sVal

Comment: Im unable to download any library from OFFice network

Comment: IDictionary<string,object>  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

```
string data = "{\"bVal\":true,\"sVal\":\"kkkk\"}";
object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(data);
```

Output Should be

```
{[bVal, True]}
{[sVal, kkkk]}
```

You can also do in other way as @icepickle suggested above

```
string json = "{\"bVal\":true,\"sVal\":\"kkkk\"}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
Dictionary<string, object> values = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

and you should get same output in form of dictionary